Angular Circular dependency problem in test case
i have a component that have circular dependency and followed this article
everything is working but failed test case which i unable to solve this
@Component({
    selector: 'my-list',
    templateUrl: './list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    standalone: true,
    imports: [forwardRef(() => CustomTypeComponent)]
})

test
describe('listOffersComponent', () => {
    let component: ListComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ListComponent],
            providers: []
        })
            .compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    // TODO: need to solve how to provide testbed with circular dependency, did not find solutuon
    // eslint-disable-next-line jest/no-disabled-tests
    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});

error
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp')

       9 |
      10 |     beforeEach(async () => {
    > 11 |         await TestBed.configureTestingModule({

try to import ref component in imports section but still no luck, does anyone face this issue to fix the test
to reproduce, run npm run test

are you using jest?

yes, jest is using

I might be mistaken, but if you import 'imports: [forwardRef(() => CustomTypeComponent)]' in your ListComponent(@Component) shouldn't you also import the CustomTypeComponent in the Test and just declare the ListComponent there?
something like:
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ListComponent]
        imports: [forwardRef(() => CustomTypeComponent)],
    })
        .compileComponents();
});


unfortunately not, as list component is standalone comp, it should not be in declarations, should be in imports only (tried your solution and got that error)

forwardRef other way around then only test get's pass (parent component forward from child), do not see better option to fix this with in test suite

I see, sorry that i coudn't help. The last time I had a circular dependency I solved it with not having one in the first place (which should be the go to imo), but I guess this is not an option for you. Hope someone else can help you!
